# Função para adicionar mais horas ou dias a uma data

Tags: javascript

Não sei mexer muito com a função `new Date()` e queria uma forma de adicionar dias/horas em um data.

### Exemplo:

Eu tenho:

```
var Time = "14/03/2014 23:54";
```

e quero adicionar 2 horas ao **Time**, então ele adiciona as 2 horas e acrescenta 1 ao dia.

```
var Time = "15/03/2014 01:54";
```

Se for no caso do mês ele adiciona 3 e se caso chegar ao fim do ano ele já coloca como 2015.

Eu estava precisando desse código urgente, porem não sei como fazer (acho que deve mexer muito com `new Date()`). Conto com a ajuda de vocês!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assim:

## Horas

```
var time = new Date('2014-03-14T23:54:00');
var outraData = new Date();
outraData.setHours(time.getHours() + 2); // Adiciona 2 horas
```

## Dias

```
var time = new Date('2014-03-14T23:54:00');
var outraData = new Date();
outraData.setDate(time.getDate() + 3); // Adiciona 3 dias
```

Comment: Não deveria ser `var outraData = new Date(time.getTime());`?

Comment: Pode ser também. Só quis explicitar que é um objeto novo.

Comment: CiganoMorrisonMendez, bfavaretto estou com um problema, eu defino uma data na função Date mas por algum motivo vem 3 horas a menos, ex: "2014-04-25T06:46:00" = "Fri Apr 25 2014 03:46:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)". O que causa isso? Tentei usar setUTCHours() e coloquei o número 9 (setUTCHours(9)) e veio o resultado esperado mas é aconselhável usar ou tem outro jeito melhor?

Comment: @IagoBruno Acho que vale a pena abrir uma nova pergunta para esta nova dúvida.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez nesta validação outraData.setDate(time.getDate() + 3); // Adiciona 3 dias
eu não consigo usar datas do mesmo mês, ex: se eu coloco 01/01/2017 eu não consigo usar 20/01/2017, mais eu consigo usar 01/02/2017, poderia me ajudar a arumar isso ?

Comment: @LeonardoMacedo Não entendi seu problema.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Já consegui resolver!

Comment: @LeonardoMacedo como resolveu?

Answer (score 15):

Só para complementar: dependendo do projeto, pode ser uma boa ideia usar a biblioteca [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com), que cuida muito bem desse tipo de situação.

Você pode fazer coisas como isso aqui:

```
// Criar uma data e adicionar duas horas
var minhaData = moment(
    "14/03/2014 23:54", "D/M/YYYY h:m"
).add(
    'hours', 2
);

// Retornar string "calendário" humanizada
minhaData.calendar(); // "Tomorrow at 1:54 AM" (também dá para fazer em português)

// Retornar objeto Date
minhaData.toDate(); // Sat Mar 15 2014 01:54:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)
```

Comment: Nota: antes de adicionar o Moment em um projeto novo, leia [esta documentação](https://momentjs.com/docs/) para saber o que está fazendo. Citando uma parte: "_In most cases, you should not choose Moment for new projects. However there are some possible reasons you might want to keep using it._"

Answer (score 13):

Você quer uma função para fazer somar à data para você, esta é uma tarefa fácil. Como podes ver na [resposta do Leonel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9282/), talvez não precise de uma função, porém já que você *quer* uma função, você pode vincular uma no `Prototype` do próprio objeto `Date`, que seria declarar o seguinte:

```
Date.prototype.addHoras = function(horas){
    this.setHours(this.getHours() + horas)
};
Date.prototype.addMinutos = function(minutos){
    this.setMinutes(this.getMinutes() + minutos)
};
Date.prototype.addSegundos = function(segundos){
    this.setSeconds(this.getSeconds() + segundos)
};
Date.prototype.addDias = function(dias){
    this.setDate(this.getDate() + dias)
};
Date.prototype.addMeses = function(meses){
    this.setMonth(this.getMonth() + meses)
};
Date.prototype.addAnos = function(anos){
    this.setYear(this.getFullYear() + anos)
};
```

**Obs:** Note que além do que você pediu (horas ou dias) eu adicionei também a funcionalidade para horas, minutos, segundos, dias, meses e anos.

Após a declaração dos métodos, você pode utilizá-los da seguinte forma:

```
//Criando uma data sem parâmetros (tempo atual)
var dt = new Date();
//Exemplo adicionando 1 hora na sua data
dt.addHora(1);
//Exemplo adicionando 30 minutos na sua data
dt.addMinutos(30);
//Exemplo adicionando 15 segundos na sua data
dt.addSegundos(15);
//Exemplo adicionando 10 dias na sua data
dt.addDias(10);
//Exemplo adicionando 2 meses na sua data:
dt.addMeses(2);
//Exemplo adicionando 1 ano na sua data:
dt.addAnos(1);
//Imprimindo ela no console
console.log(dt);
```

Desta forma você pode adicionar *horas/minutos/segundos/dias/meses/anos* à sua data facilmente.

Answer (score -1):

Todos estão simplesmente somando o dia, e se for o ultimo dia do mes? e se for ano bissexto. não sei se essa abordagem ai da certo não. o que eu prefiro fazer caso não possa usar libs externas é converter para milissegundos e somar com a quantidade que eu quero. depois disso converto pra data

```
const SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60;
const MINUTES_PER_HOUR = 60;
const MILISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
const HOURS_PER_DAY = 24;

const today = new Date()
const oneDayInMiliSeconds = SECONDS_PER_MINUTE * MINUTES_PER_HOUR * MILISECONDS_PER_SECOND * HOURS_PER_DAY;
const tomorow = new Date((today.getTime()+oneDayInMiliSeconds))
```

Comment: Dá certo sim, pois ao somar dias, ele já ajusta para o mês seguinte (e até para o ano seguinte) caso seja necessário, e também trata de anos bissextos, veja aqui: https://ideone.com/lMPnC0 - Lembrando ainda que somar 1 dia nem sempre é o mesmo que somar a quantidade de milissegundos equivalente a 24 horas, pois temos esquisitices que podem acontecer devido ao horário de verão: https://ideone.com/wdpwaN

Comment: Cara, interessante, realmente funciona. achei que simplesmente somaria só o dia sem somar meses a anos, valeu