# Somar dias a uma data dentro do método e retorná-la com novo período

Tags: javascript

Tentei fazer uma função para somar a essa data, dias vindo de um parâmetro passado na função. Abaixo a função:

```
function montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(){

    var exclusao = new Date('2014-03-14T23:54:00');
    var novadata = new Date();
    var p = 60;

    //lblTeste
    novadata.setDate(exclusao.getDate() + p);

    alert(exclusao);
    alert(p);
    alert(novadata);
}
```

Alterei a função, pois a data que deveria vir por parâmetro, estava dando erro de `NaN`. Removi o segundo parâmetro também, que seria os dias somados, mas esse estava correto, troquei pelo "P", mas não é esse o problema. Acontece que no `alert(exclusao)` está vindo um `NaN` e claro `novadata` também está vindo assim. Como eu somo dias a uma data em js? Tirei isso do colega Morrison, [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9281/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-adicionar-mais-horas-ou-dias-a-uma-data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está adicionando 60 dias com base na data atual `new Date()`, você precisa utilizar o `setDate()` utilizando a data de exclusão.

```
var exclusao = new Date('2014-03-14T23:54:00');
var novaData = exclusao;
novaData.setDate(novaData.getDate() + 60);
```

Comment: Mas exclusao está vindo como: NaN

Comment: Tinha feito um fiddle e funcionou certinho usando `console.log` mas deveria mostrar certo com `alert`

Comment: Comigo não está funcionando, marquei como resposta, pois um teste que fiz funcionou, mas com data montada, mas pelo código não funcionou e por isso resolvi colocar esse comentário. Será que é porque a data está vindo sem a parte hora?

Comment: Fiz no fiddle e veja como está. Não funciona: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pnet/ed3m6t4o/)

Comment: @pnet Pra você conseguir adicionar dias na data você precisa ter um objeto do tipo `Date`. no exemplo que você fez no fiddle está usando uma `string`. Note a seguinte mensagem no console do navegador `Uncaught TypeError: dt_exclusao.getDate is not a function`

Comment: Eu sei, mas o formato que é recebido pelo parâmetro da função é string e já dei um `Date.parse()`. um `stringTodate()` e nada aconteceu. Não estou conseguindo parsear de um formato para outro.

Comment: De fato, só irá funcionar com uma variável `Date` válida. Caso tenha dúvida como formatar, pode fazer uma pergunta aqui no SO. De antemão, pode dar uma lida [na referência do tipo Date aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma função que eu uso em JAVASCRIPT...

```
function somaDias(dt,qtd)
{
    var dt1 = dt.split("/");
    var hj1 = dt1[2]+"-"+dt1[1]+"-"+dt1[0];
    var dtat = new Date(hj1);
    dtat.setDate(dtat.getDate());
    var myDate = new Date(hj1);
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + (qtd+1));
    var ano = myDate.getFullYear();
    var dia = myDate.getDate(); if(dia<10){dia='0'+dia};
    var mes = (myDate.getMonth()+1); if(mes<10){mes='0'+mes}        
    return (dia+"/"+mes+"/"+ano);
}

// Informe a data e a quantidade de dias que deseja somar.
alert(somaDias('31/03/2017',1));
```

Comment: Jetro, bemvindo! Evita colocar respostas duplicadas. Se as perguntas forem sobre o mesmo problema marca-as como duplicadas. Até breve!

Comment: Olá, Sergio. Não entendi seu comentário. Onde posso ver se a pergunta é sobre "Um mesmo problema" ?

Comment: Oi! Deste a mesma resposta aqui que nesta outra pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/194415/129 Daí o meu comentário. Normalmente a mesma resposta (sem mudar uma virgula) é muito provável que a pergunta seja a mesma e então deve ser sinalizada como duplicada.