# Como somar data, a partir de uma Data e Numero de dias digitado pelo usuário

Tags: javascript

Estou precisando somar uma data, a partir de uma "data de compra" e dias em prazo de validade.

No `console.log` estou capturando os dados que preciso, porem na hora da soma da data está gerando uma data incorreta.

```
function addDays(){
   var data = $('#dataCompra').val();
   var dias = $('#tipoproduto').val();
   console.log(dias);
   var result = new Date(data);
   console.log(data);
   console.log(dias);
   result.setDate(result.getDate() + dias);

   console.log(result);
   $('#dataValidade').val(result);

};

</script>
```

Em uma data que era pra somar 5 dias, que o foi o valor digitado e capturado no console, ele calcula uma data não esperada:

```
5
2016-10-10
5
Date 2017-01-03T23:00:00.000Z
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poderia modificar a função de data pra que seja capaz de adicionar dias a sua data, como por exemplo:

**Solução em JQuery**
Fiz esse **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/viniciusColares/fhdgwuzL/)** utilizando a lib **[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)** pra uma solução completa em tempo e data.

```
<input type="number" id="num_dias"><button id="gerar">Gerar Data</button>
<input disabled type="date" id="vencimento">

$(function(){
  $("#gerar").on('click', function(){
    var numDays = $("#num_dias").val();
    var venc = moment().add(numDays, 'd').format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    $("#vencimento").val(venc);
    $("#out").html("Adicionado " + numDays + " dias ao total do vencimento");
  });
});
```

Comment: Desculpa, mas não consegui executar esse metodo...

Comment: Ele funciona com o onblur? preciso digitar uma data de compra e o onblur chama o metodo, calcula a data e o metodo precisa retornar no campo dataValidade...

Comment: A solução precisa usar javascript puro? Ou pode ser em Jquery? Eu testei essa função no console e funcionou

Comment: Agora sim, só ajustei as variáveis para o meu form e funcionou certinho.. Uma outra duvida, eu consigo calcular a data a partir de uma data digitada, utilizando o moment?

Comment: Consegue sim, a biblioteca moment.js é SUPER completa, vc só precisaria parsear a data digitada, e garantir que o usuário digitaria uma data válida

Comment: Legal... Vou estudar aqui então.. me ajudou muito.. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma função que eu uso em JAVASCRIPT...

```
function somaDias(dt,qtd)
{
    var dt1 = dt.split("/");
    var hj1 = dt1[2]+"-"+dt1[1]+"-"+dt1[0];
    var dtat = new Date(hj1);
    dtat.setDate(dtat.getDate());
    var myDate = new Date(hj1);
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + (qtd+1));
    var ano = myDate.getFullYear();
    var dia = myDate.getDate(); if(dia<10){dia='0'+dia};
    var mes = (myDate.getMonth()+1); if(mes<10){mes='0'+mes}        
    return (dia+"/"+mes+"/"+ano);
}

// Informe a data e a quantidade de dias que deseja somar.
alert(somaDias('31/03/2017',1));
```