# Somar dias a data atual

Tags: javascript, html, data

Preciso pegar a data atual e somar dias de acordo com o selecionado

```js
function calcular(){
    var valor1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('dias1').value);
    var valor2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('dias2').value);
    var valor3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('dias3').value);
    document.getElementById('diassomado').value = valor1 + valor2 + valor3;
} 
 


 function RetornaDataHoraAtual(){
  var dNow = new Date();
  var localdate = dNow.getDate() + '/' + (dNow.getMonth()+1) + '/' + dNow.getFullYear();
  document.getElementById('dataatual').value = localdate;
  
  return localdate;
  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="row">
 <label>Dias 1</label>
 <select id="dias1" >
  
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  
  
  
 </select>
 <label>Dias 2</label>
  <select id="dias2" >
  
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  
  
  
 </select>
 
 <label>Dias 3</label>
  <select id="dias3" >
  
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  
  
  
 </select>
 </div>
 
 <div class="row">
 <label>Dias</label>
 <input type="text" id="diassomado" ><br>
 
 <label>Data Atual</label>
 <input type="text" id="dataatual" ><br>
 
 <label>Data Somada</label>
 <input type="text" id="datasomada" >
 
</div>

<input type="button" onClick="calcular(), RetornaDataHoraAtual()" value="Gerar">


</body>
</html>
```

Exemplo 
5 dias 
data atual
10/05/2018
Resultado
15/05/2018

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como somar data, a partir de uma Data e Numero de dias digitado pelo usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160065/como-somar-data-a-partir-de-uma-data-e-numero-de-dias-digitado-pelo-usu%c3%a1rio)

Answer (score 1):

```js
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
  dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
  return dat;
}

var dat = new Date();

alert(dat.addDays(5))
```