# Intervalo de datas

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou usando o type date do HTML 5, para o usuário fornecer uma data.

```
<input type="date" name="data-inicial">
<input type="date" name="data-final">
```

Existem dois campos: Data inicial e Data final, porém a data final tem que ser no máximo 29 dias após a data inicial. Ou seja, se a pessoal selecionar a data inicial de 23/07/2018, ela tem um intervalo de no máximo 29 dias após essa data, para selecionar a data final.

Comment: Você pode pegar a data inicial, que o usuário informou, [somar 29 dias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160065/5878) e definir como valor da data final. Quer tentar fazer assim?

Comment: Mas eu nao quero definir uma data final, eu quero impedir que a pessoa selecione uma data acima dos 29 dias da data inicial, tem como?

Comment: Tem, a lógica é a mesma que citei: basta somar 29 dias à data inicial com JavaScript e definí-la como data final, mas sua pergunta não está clara. Por favor, edite-a e adicione o HTML.

Comment: Editei, dá uma olhada agora

Comment: Então, com o que eu comentei antes você consegue fazer isso. Você pode definir a data máxima através do atributo `max`. Tente fazer assim, te dou certeza que funciona e é fácil.

Comment: deixo o min em branco e o max com 29?

Comment: Não, atente-se aos termos: *somar 29 dias* - inclusive coloquei como link para onde explica como fazer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um exemplo de como pode ser feito...

HTML5

```
<input type='date' id='d1' name='d1' min="">
<input type='date' id='d2' name='d2' min="">
```

JS (JQuery)

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#d1").change(function () {
        var split = $("#d1").val().split('-');
        var fim = new Date(parseInt(split[0]), parseInt(split[1]), parseInt(split[2]) + 29);
        $("#d2").attr({
           "min" : [fim.getFullYear(), 
                (fim.getMonth() > 9 ? '' : '0') + fim.getMonth(), 
                (fim.getDate() > 9 ? '' : '0') + fim.getDate()]
                .join('-')
        });
      });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde amigo :D

Quando você subtrai uma data de outra você obtêm um [timestamp](https://www.epochconverter.com/) basta converte-lo para o formato desejado segue exemplo pratico:

### Explicação:

1. Primeiro obtenho os inputs no inicio da pagina com o [document.getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) como ele me retorna um array pego o primeiro como o nome da busca.
2. Logo vem o metodo **checar** que por sua vez, obtêm os valores de cada input e crio uma instancia do objeto [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).
3. Por fim realizo a subtração de uma data pela outra e utilizo o [Math.abs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) para caso o inicio seja maior que o fim ele torna a diferença negativa para positiva.
4. Divido para 1000.0 para deixar no formato de [unixtimestamp](https://www.epochconverter.com/)
5. E divido por 86400 para obter a diferença em dias.
6. Por fim verifico se a diferença é maior que 29 caso sim exibo um [alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert).

```js
const dataInicial = document.getElementsByName('data-inicial')[0];
const dataFinal = document.getElementsByName('data-final')[0];

function checar() {
  const inicio = new Date(dataInicial.value);
  const fim = new Date(dataFinal.value);
  
  const diferenca = Math.abs(inicio - fim) / 1000.0;
  const diferencaEmDias = diferenca/86400;

  //
  // Tabela timestamp
  //
  /*    1 Hr      |    3600 Seg        */
  /*    1 Dia     |    86400 Seg       */
  /*    1 Semana  |    604800 Seg      */
  /*    1 Mes     |    2629743 Seg     */
  /*    1 Ano     |    31556926 Seg    */


  console.log(`${diferencaEmDias} dias de diferença`);
  
  if (diferencaEmDias > 29) {
    alert('Maior que o limite');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="data-inicial">
<input type="date" name="data-final">
<button onclick="checar()">DIFERENÇA</button>
```

Existem bibliotecas que facilitam o trabalho com Datas por exemplo o [MomentJs](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Tem como eu pegar o "name" que coloquei no input?

Comment: @PRibeiro Acho que foi oque entendi... Espero ter ajudado! :)