# Como acrescentar mais um dia usando "new Date()"

Tags: javascript

Olá, estou com essa função, mais não sei como coloco um dia a mais na data, alguém pode me ajudar.

```
var myVar = setTimeout(function(){ myTimer() });

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    var options = {weekday: 'long', month: 'long', year: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' }
    var t = d.toLocaleDateString('pt-br', (options));
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;

}
```

Comment: O meu e tipo string, pode ser considerada diferente?

Comment: Olá Léo, aonde exatamente esta a tal string? A parte de somar um dia ou mais esta bem explicado na pergunta que linkei, não concorda? A string que se refere é vinda do servidor?

Comment: Eu estou começando agora, achei que essa pergunta e as respostas são mais fáceis, e o string que digo e a forma que ele é exibido  na tela. "sábado, 1 de julho de 2017".

Comment: Mas a sua pergunta não fala de como exibir na tela e nem as respostas do Renan e do Mateus falam disto, na verdade o seu código já faz a parte de exibir, a duvida só parece mesmo sobre "somar", se for por um detalhe ou outro quase todas perguntas que eu fizer que tiver um `;` diferente deixariam de ser duplicata, não concorda? ;) ... Agora se o teu problema é também exibir, isto teria que estar descrito no corpo da pergunta, não concorda?

Comment: Concordo, mais essa pergunta vai ser apagada?

Comment: Léo duplicatas não são perguntas banidas nem do mal nem nada, são fechadas apenas para impedir de receber respostas e evitar descentralizar o assunto e ainda ficam linkadas a pergunta principal o que é ótimo para ajudar os usuários a procurarem várias respostas nas diferentes perguntas. Não há nada o que se preocupar.... Recomendo muito que leia este link: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635 ;D

Comment: Vlw, muito iniciante ainda, rsrsrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maneira canônica, cross-browswer, documentada e que funciona em qualquer lugar é você somar a quantidade de milissegundos de um dia à sua data.

I.e.:

```
var agora = new Date();
var agoraAmanha = new Date(agora.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
// essa é a quantidade de milissegundos em 24 horas.
```

O motivo disso é que:

- Somar um a data é um comportamento do navegador. Não é garantido que todos os navegadores vão ter o mesmo comportamento, nem que o mesmo navegador vá ter o mesmo comportamento em todos os dispositivos. Fora outros ambientes como Node.js. Não estou dizendo que não dê certo em todos os ambientes que você for usar... Só acho a solução acima mais garantida.
- Você poderia também usar o método [setDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) do tipo Date. Nos ambientes em que testei, somar um dia faz o que você quer. Setar o dia 32 de Março, por exemplo, faz com que você obtenha uma data no dia primeiro de Abril. Mas mais uma vez, não há garantias de se ter esse comportamento em todos os ambientes.

Comment: Vlw, resposta completíssima, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Acrescente uma linha:

```
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
```

o código ficará:

```
    var myVar = setTimeout(function(){ myTimer() });

    function myTimer() {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
        var options = {weekday: 'long', month: 'long', year: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' }
        var t = d.toLocaleDateString('pt-br', (options));
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;

    }
```

Não precisa preocupar com o último dia do mês ou do ano, porque o *JavaScript date* é inteligente em termos de *rollover*.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, ajudo bastante mesmo.

Comment: Lembre-se você também pode verificar se já não existe respostas no site sobre o assunto e ao invés de responder você poderia usar o Sinalizar e marcar com duplicata de por exemplo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9281/3635, assim você pode nos ajudar a colaborar com a organização do site ;D

Comment: Vlw pela dica Guilherme.